# Frequency wavenumber

Tags: frequency, turbulence

Usually, when you have to go from frequency to wavenumber you have to adopt the following equation:

$$k = \frac{2\pi f}{U}$$
where *k* is the wavenumber, *f* is the frequency and *U* is the velocity.

Where does this equation come from? Is this a consequence of the Taylor Hypothesis? Is this formula always reliable?
(I am studying turbulence)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waves are periodic solutions with a phase given by $\phi(x,t) = kx - \omega t$, where $\omega = 2\pi f$. The point of a constant phase is thus moving with a speed that can be determined from this relation: $$d\phi(x,t) = kdx -\omega dt = 0,$$
that is the *phase speed* is $$v_{ph} = \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\omega}{k}=\frac{2\pi f}{k} = \frac{2\pi f}{2\pi/\lambda} =\lambda f,$$
where $\lambda$ is the wave length. This is also where the relation in question comes from.

In addition to the *phase speed* one often defines defines a *group speed*, which describes propagation of *wave packets*, i.e. groups of waves with a distribution of frequencies and wave vectors. I just state the result without the lengthy math:
$$v_g = \frac{d\omega(k)}{dk}.$$

In vacuum and many media the frequency linearly depends on the wavenumber, $\omega = v_{ph}k$, so that the group and the phase speeds are the same. When this is not the case we speak of *dispersion* and *dispersive media*.

**Remarks**
The group speed is less than the phase speed. It is usually said that information propagates with the group speed, since a plane wave by itself cannot carry any information: it is predictable in all the space. This has to do with some paradoxes in relativity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the fact that the frequency linearly depends on the wavenumber related only to the media or  can it be related also with the pheonomena? If I have an Energy spectrum in frequency can I always obtain an Energy spectrum in wavenumber using the formula that I wrote in the first post?

Comment: When speaking about the electromagnetic waves, it is nearly always that $\omega = ck$, where $c$ is the speed of light (adjusted for the dielectric constants of the media). In this context nonlinearity has to do only with the media. 

On the other hand, when speaking of the matter waves in quantum mechanics we usually have $\omega = \hbar k^2/(2m)$, so that one speaks more frequently of the *speed* meaning the *group speed*: $v=\hbar k /m$. In relativity or solid state physics the relationship between the frequency and the wavenumber may be even more complicated.

Comment: what about if we speak about turbulence in a fluid?

Comment: Turbulence is not simple waves, or perhaps not waves at all.

Comment: You are right. But it is analysed using the spectral theory.